# Flutter SharedPreferences Windows location

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Where does [`SharedPreferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) save local data on Windows?  Like where is the path?  I am referring to this:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var myData = prefs.getString('myData');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Shared Preferences documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), it's stored in the local AppData folder for Windows.

From a scan of the code for the [Windows platform interface](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences_windows/lib/shared_preferences_windows.dart), this seems to be the path obtained by `pathProvider.getApplicationSupportPath()`. You could call this in your code to get the specific path of where the file is stored.

Comment: The value from printing getApplicationSupportPath:  C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\[companyname]\[projectname]

Comment: So it's %appdata%\CompanyName\ProductName\shared_preferences.json from windows\runner\Runner.rc

Answer (score 0):

It has moved apparently to \AppData\Local\Packages\YOURPACKAGE\LocalCache\Roaming\com.COMPANYNAME\APPNAME

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Flutter stores the shared pref key-value pairs in the location `Users\YOUR-USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\com.COMPANYNAME\APPNAME\shared-preferences.json`